# quake like console in javascript (and jquery if it can help)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to do a console like on quake : http://klickverbot.at/blog/2011/02/quake-style-terminal-on-osx/quake4-console.png

When you press tilde, it drop down from the top of the screen, overlapping half of the screen, if you press again tidle, it disappear totally.

The question is how to create an area where you can display some log/text with a browser scroll bar and so on without iframe? http://lifehacker.com/ seems to do it, there's 2 scrollbars that scroll only a part of the webpage.

And is jquery or/and jquery ui gives some easier way to achieve it?

Comment: you want to know the tilde thing or the scrollbar thing?

Comment: scrollbar. I agree i wasn't clear enough: The question is how to create an area where you can display some long log/text with a browser scrollbar without iframe?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you go. [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/huxXT/10/) showing how to use jquery to capture the `~` key and slide down a console div.

**UPDATE WITH SCROLLBARS**

http://jsfiddle.net/huxXT/19/

Comment: Make the console position fixed to avoid body scroll and I'll +1. Also use `e.which`

Comment: fiddle doesn't seem to work for me, even after adding some text to the div.

Comment: still not triggering on `~` or `\``

Comment: What browser? Works for me..!

Comment: to be clear, this will trigger using ` key (the default key from  Quake)

Comment: @Dutchie432: Firefox 3.6.x on Mac OS X, and Firefox 3.6.x on Win XP.

Comment: Thanks for the console part. My question was in fact, how to display a long text inside the console with a scrollbar but without iframe

Comment: Instead of an iframe, use a div and set `overflow:scroll` like in this link: http://jsfiddle.net/huxXT/19/ - notice the long text in my `window` div and in my CSS window is set for `overflow:scroll`

Comment: Really great Dutchie432, i didn't expected the whole working code. I discovered jsfiddle, awesome.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Now triggers on `~` in addition to the back-tick.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VazC8/2/)**

```
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 96 || e.which == 126) {
        $('#console').slideToggle();
    }
});
```

Comment: @Dutchie432: It's `126` on the two systems I have here: Mac OS X and Win XP. (en-US)

Comment: Okay that explains why this didn't work for you. I got my code of `192` by pressing the button and coding `alert(e.which)`. However, your `96` or `126` also works - please retry my link and see if it now works for you (http://jsfiddle.net/huxXT/10/). +1 for helping.

Comment: @Dutchie432: That's how I got my keycodes as well. Srsly, "helping"? Your code is an exact copy of mine.

Comment: Yeah - you helped me simplify my code, which was working just fine once I sorted out the keycode issue. Turns out not to be what the OP wanted anyway.