# JavaScript library to implement command line in browser

Tags: javascript, browser, command-line-interface

I would like to allow powerusers to perform certain actions on the site in a command-line like interface (think Quake console that slides in from above ;-). Is there a library that already implements the basics of what I need in the browser? Tasks like getting the input from the user, command history etc. Me and my colleagues will have limited time to implement this during a hackathon, so we want to have as much time as possible to implement the actual commands interfacing with our app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [quake like console in javascript (and jquery if it can help)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873187/quake-like-console-in-javascript-and-jquery-if-it-can-help)

Comment: Please update Q&A format, this question really helped me.

Comment: I disagree that this question is a bad fit. The question is "Is there a library that already implements the basics of what I need in the browser?" That's not a matter of opinion. Moreover, the replies have been fact-based (and helpful to me), and there has been no argument, polling, etc.

Comment: This is a useful question. May be the title is misleading.. One of new library (in 2021) to do this is [Xterm.js](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js). Refer to README --> "Xterm.js is a front-end component written in TypeScript that lets applications bring fully-featured terminals to their users in the browser. It's used by popular projects such as VS Code, Hyper and Theia".

Answer (score 12):

Have a look at Josh.js for a bash-like environment in the browser:

- http://sdether.github.com/josh.js/

Answer (score 6):

Of course there is also the excellent `termlib` found [here](http://www.masswerk.at/termlib/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

You may find this project helpful:

https://github.com/chjj/tty.js

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [JavaScript shells](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Shells) from mozilla.org

See also [Jash: JavaScript Shell](http://www.billyreisinger.com/jash/)

Comment: Seems the Mozilla Javascript Shells are mostly "standalone", i.e. *not* "in the browser", but `Jash` looks browser-based